# Qt C++ ComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

```
QList<QString> list;
list << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4" << "5";
ui->comboBox->addItems(list);
QString number = "3";
```

Как сделать так, если нашлась цифра 3 в списке `comboBox` то выбирается цифра 3 в этом же списке как `currentItem` на той же позиции что и цифра 3 в `comboBox`? Т.е по нажатию `comboBox` выделение цифры 3 стоит на 3-й позиции.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните понятней, чего вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 4):

[int QComboBox::findText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#findText) + **setCurrentIndex** если нашли

Answer (score 0):

```
         ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(number);
```

Comment: Если полный пример: ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(ui->comboBox.findText("3"));